# Spring Cloud Consul: report not IP but DNS name to Consul Cluster

Tags: spring-cloud, consul, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-consul

In my Spring Cloud Consul, I found out that program reports itself with IP address of the node, rather than DNS name.

I need to report it using DNS name. How I could configure that?

Comment: it should be default report the hostname. What is your configuration? What are your dependencies? How are you running? Please provide more detail.

Comment: Why do you need to use the hostname vs the DNS name?

Comment: Dns name is ok, the problem is that I am getting Ip